# Django, fetching data of other users

Tags: django, django-forms

I used [Django’s built in authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/) to create a log in, sign up and log out function. I want to add the ability to change your bio so that other users can view that bio through your profile page.

Below is my code:

**register.html template**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <h3 class="Logged">You must log out first before you can register a new account</h3>
      {% else %}
      <div class="signup">
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <p>Username: </p>
          {{ form.username }}<br>
          <p>Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only. Password: </p>
          {{ form.password1 }}<br>
          <p>Your password can't be too similar to your other personal information. Your password must contain at least 8 characters. Your password can't be a commonly used password. Your password can't be entirely numeric.</p>
          <p>Password Confirmation: </p>
          {{ form.help_text}}
          {{ form.password2 }}<br>
          <p>Enter the same password as before, for verification</p>
          {% if form.errors %}
          <p class="invalid">What you have entered is invalid</p>
          {% endif %}
          <input type="submit" = value="Register">
          <br><br>
        </form>
      </div>
{% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login', views.log, name='log'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('accounts', views.accounts, name='accounts'),
]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Not without seeing some code. But viewing and editing user data isn't any different from any other data, so you'll need to be more explicit  about where you're having problems.

Comment: I've just added the code

Comment: So you need to view another users profile on the page?

Comment: Yes exactly thank you

Comment: If this is solved, click on the tick next to the answer to accept it please. We don't edit titles for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**URLS.PY**

```
from yourapp import views as yourapp_views
url(r'^user/(?P<user_login_name>[\w\-]+)/$', extension_views.view_user_profile)
```

**YOURAPP.VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render

def view_user_profile(request, user_login_name):
    args = {}
    args['user_profile'] = User.objects.get(username=user_login_name)
    return render(request, 'your_template_to_render.html', args)
```

**your_template_to_render.html**

{{ user_profile }} 
 {{ user_profile.id }} 
 {{ user_profile.firstname }}

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! It worked. Me and my friend has been trying to figure it out for ages

Comment: You welcome! You can add my linked in account https://www.linkedin.com/in/%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%B2-39b091166/ so it will be easy to ask some general question